# Best practice: Javascript/Jquery saving variable for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure, this question has been answered somewhere before but I just couldn't find it.

If within a function a variable has been defined, what is the best practice to save it for later use?  1. Saving it "globally"?
`foo = 'bar';
...
function bar(){

       ...

       foo = 'bat';

       return foo;

     }
...`

Here, the variable will be altered later on.
 2. Or saving it within a hidden form field within the HTML-DOM?

`Thanxs!

Comment: Depends on how it is to be used and why. If its only to be used in the same function you could store it as a property on the function name bar["foo"] = "", but if it is to be used elsewhere it might be better to declare it there fro mthe beginning.

Comment: Note: I think you might want to edit it to say `foo = "bar"; function bar(){ ... foo = "bat"; return foo; }`. At least that is how I read the question.

Comment: This is en exaple of how I thought: 
function c() {
  if(typeof c["1"] == "undefined")
   c["1"] = 1;
  document.write(c["1"]++);
 }
 
 c();
It works as a static variable.

Comment: By the way, how do I highlight code in comments ;)

Comment: @David Mårtensson, Backticks surrounding your code. (The key is probably just below your ESC key). Looks like this: ` (This can be used for inline code in Qs and As too)

Comment: Puuuuh. Honestly, I am confused! I guess for now and 'till HTML5 is more established I'll be saving variables globally BudgieInWA's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving it as a global JavaScript variable is by far the most efficient.

**EDIT**: If the data you want to save is associated with an element on the page (for example, each row in a table has a bit of data associated with it), and you are using jQuery, there is a [data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which is more efficient than setting an attribute on the element or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but probably: In a variable defined at the top level of a closure that wraps the set of functions to which it applies.

i.e.

```
var exports = function () {
    var stored_data;
    function set_data(foo) {
        stored_data = foo;
    }
    function get_data() {
        return stored_data;
    }
    return { get: get_data, set: set_data };
}();
```

This avoids the risk of other scripts (or other parts of your own, potentially very large, script) overwriting it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 spec has defined a solution to this question: If you are using HTML5, you can specify data attributes in your DOM.

See this page for more info: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

This is now the standardised way of doing it, so I guess that it's considered best practice. Also John Resig, who wrote the blog I linked to above, is the author of JQuery, so if it's good enough for him, who am I to argue.

The really good news is that you don't even have to be using an HTML5-compatible browser for this technique to work - it already works in older browsers; it's just that now it's been encoded into the standard, and there's a defined way to do it.

That said, there's nothing wrong with a global variable in your Javascript as long as you avoid polluting the namespace too much, and it would be more efficient from a performance perspective, so there's plenty of merit in that approach as well.

Comment: Hi Spudley, thanks for your answer. I just tried Resig's way. However using attributes like "data-name" is presently invalid Code (W3C) when using XHTML 1.0 Strict :-(

Comment: @Mike: John Resig's blog does discuss briefly how to do it in XHTML (additional namespace), and links to another blog that discusses it in more detail. However, I would suggest moving away from XHTML strict anyway now. XHTML has had its day; HTML5 is a far more powerful spec, and you'll lose functionality going forward if you don't make the jump sooner or later (and at this stage, it's just a change to your doctype, so it's an easy jump to make).